# Get Label through Function

Tags: vb.net

all! I'm developing a BlackJack game but I've run into a little bit of a problem. When calculating score, I have to type YourCard1.Text, YourCard2.Text, YourCard3.Text, etc.
Can I make a function that gets the right label each time it's called? I want to do this so I don't have to type so much...

For example, instead of typing out "YourCard1.Text", I want to be able to type "card(1)" Is this possible? I've tried multiple ways of doing this, but to no avail. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work.

Comment: if `card` was an array of labels, `card(n).Text` would work

Comment: The right way to do this would be to make a class called Card, and have a list of Cards. Then each time the card is changed, it alerts the UI to update the appropriate Label. It's usually not a good idea to actually store information on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have those labels on your form, YourCard1.Text, YourCard2.Text, YourCard3.Text, etc., This function should work for you. It returns the Label itself, not the Text property.

```
Private Function card(index As Integer) As Label
    Try
        Return Me.Controls.
            OfType(Of Label).
            Where(Function(l) l.Name = "YourCard" & index.ToString()).
            Single()
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Note: `Me.Controls` returns the controls directly inside the form, but doesn't return controls inside containers in the form. If your cards are inside a panel, `Panel1` for example, you would do `Return Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)...`

Usage:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    card(1).Text = "Hello"
    card(2).Text = "World"
End Sub
```

[image]

Edit to address comment.

You are pidgeonholed into only those semantics. So there is another way I could think of. But I wouldn't personally do this.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Class cardClass
        Private myContainer As Control
        Sub New(container As Control)
            myContainer = container
        End Sub

        Default Public WriteOnly Property Item(ByVal index As Long) As String
            Set(value As String)
                card(index).Text = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Function card(index As Integer) As Label
            Try
                Return myContainer.Controls.
                    OfType(Of Label).
                    Where(Function(l) l.Name = "YourCard" & index.ToString()).
                    Single()
            Catch
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim card As New cardClass(Me)
        card(1) = "Hello"
        card(2) = "World"
    End Sub

End Class
```

The reason it's so complex is that though String is a reference type, it uses value type semantics. So when returning a string from a function, it can't refer back to the original memory location: it actually creates a copy of the string. So using function semantics won't work. Same would go for an array. It would be difficult (impossible?) to modify a string from either a function or array and have it modify the Label's Text property.

Comment: Ahh, I see. A bit more complex than I thought.

Comment: Would there be a way to shorten it even further? So I wouldn't have to type ".Text" every time?

Comment: I see you have used my method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050468/blackjack-wont-add-dealers-hand, please mark this as the answer