# Blackjack: Won't add Dealer's Hand

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with my blackjack game in vb.net. This code I have will add the player's score perfectly, but when it comes to the dealer's score, it will not. It only takes the second card that the dealer has.

It is called with this:

```
addScore("p")   'add player's score
addScore("d")   'add dealer's score
```

And this is "addScore()":

```
Public Function card(player As String, index As Integer) As Label
    Try
        If player = "p" Then
            Return GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(l) l.Name = "YouCard" & index.ToString()).Single()
        ElseIf player = "d" Then
            Return GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Label).Where(Function(l) l.Name = "DealerCard" & index.ToString()).Single()
        End If
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Sub addScore(ByVal player As String)
    Dim currScore As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    'Add Score
    For value As Integer = 1 To 7
        If card(player, value).Text = "A" AndAlso (currScore + 11) <= 21 Then
            result = currScore + 11
        ElseIf card(player, value).Text = "A" AndAlso (currScore + 1) <= 22 Then
            result = currScore + 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(card(player, value).Text) Then
            result = currScore + CInt(card(player, value).Text)
        ElseIf card(player, value).Text = "" Then
            result = result
        Else
            result = currScore + 10
        End If
        If player = "p" Then
            YouScore.Text = result
        Else
            DealerScore.Text = result
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `currScore` is always zero since it's never assigned any value. What is the point of it?

Comment: Are all the player's and the dealer's cards are in `GroupBox1`?

Comment: Yes, they are all in GroupBox1. What it does is reveal the dealer's first card, since the second card is always revealed... Then, it calls the addScore("d") to get the dealer's score but it always winds up with the dealer's second card x 2. So if he has a 2 and an 8, it comes up with 16 for some reason.

Comment: I am using all the code you have provided, and some default values for the cards, and I don't see that happening. My YouScore and DealerScore labels just display the last card. There must be something else you are doing which you haven't shown. Also, what is the point of `currScore`? It is always zero. Is there another declaration elsewhere in the form of a variable with the same name?

Comment: replace `currScore` with `result` and remove `Dim currScore As Integer` and it seems to work.

Comment: Wow, guys. I'm sorry to waste your time. I don't know what I was thinking when I put currScore in there. Anyways, thank you for your time and helpful advice. Everything works perfectly :)

Comment: Just one guy. Posted that as the answer.

Comment: The right thing to do now, is to click the checkmark next to the answer from @Verdolino (aka Just One Guy).  That will remove this from the Unanswered list.

Comment: ... alone on an island...

Answer (score 1):

`currScore` shouldn't be there. Replace it with `result`

```
Public Sub addScore(ByVal player As String)
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    'Add Score
    For value As Integer = 1 To 7
        If card(player, value).Text = "A" AndAlso (result + 11) <= 21 Then
            result = result + 11
        ElseIf card(player, value).Text = "A" AndAlso (result + 1) <= 22 Then
            result = result + 1
        ElseIf IsNumeric(card(player, value).Text) Then
            result = result + CInt(card(player, value).Text)
        ElseIf card(player, value).Text = "" Then
            result = result
        Else
            result = result + 10
        End If
        If player = "p" Then
            YouScore.Text = result
        Else
            DealerScore.Text = result
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```